# jquery not working to populate textboxes with gridview data

Tags: jquery, .net

I want to populate the textboxes with the data in the gridview on click of anchor tag.

i am using the below code but it is not working

function bindRecordToEdit(Id) {
        debugger;

```
    $('#txtempname').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#Employee Name:').text());
    $('#txtdept').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#txtdept').text());
    $('#txtdoj').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#DOJ').text());
    $('#Txtdob').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#DOB').text());
    $('#Txtbasic').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#Basic').text());
    $('#Txthra').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#HRA').text());
    $('#Txtda').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#DA').text());
    $('#Txtgross').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#gross').text());
    $('#Txtptax').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#Ptax').text());
    $('#Txtpfund').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#PFund').text());
    $('#Txtnetsal').val($(ele).closest('tr').find('#NetSalary').text());           
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Employeemasterjquery.aspx/bindRecordToEdit",
        data: "{'Id':" + ele + "}",
        datatype: "json",
        //async: "true",
        success: function (data) {


            //=== store id of the selected record in hidden field so that we can use it later during  
            //=== update process.  
          //  $("#hfSelectedRecord").val(id);
            //=== Hide save button and show update button.  
            //$("#btnSave").hide();  
            //$("#btnUpdate").css("display", "block");  
        },
        error: function (data) {
            var r = data.responseText;
            var errorMessage = r.Message;
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
  //  return true;   
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The first line? The last? Please be more specific in your error description.

Comment: i am not getting the value in the textboxes when i am debugging the jquery.

Comment: Please include you HTML code for better understanding. Or even better: create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your project. Also, what is the veriable `ele` ? What is stored in this variable?